# Use protobuf.js in a browser app

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I have a very simple browser application, which has to use protobuf:
https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js
I also have a '.proto' file with a message format, so I just need to encode the incoming messages with protobuf.

Unfortunately I am not able to find, how to bind protobuf in my project. All I find is about node.js, which I am not using. 
I also find some information about using require.js to bind protobuf and wrote this in my script:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    protobuf:'//cdn.rawgit.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/6.8.6/dist/protobuf.js'
  }
});
```

But it seems to be wrong, as I getthis error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (Long) {
            if (Long && Long.isLong) {
                protobuf.util.Long = Long;
                protobuf.configure();
            }
            return protobuf;
        }
```

If there's anyone who has done anything similar, would you please give me a hand here?

Thanks

Comment: did you find any solution? i have same issue?

Comment: Hey! I made it with Node JS anyway. There's also a browerfy to try.

Comment: thanks we used browserify to convert it to js.

Comment: I asked ["How to use protobuf.js in a browser with gRPC?"](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/issues/1706) on Github for this but it has been 1.5 months with no response yet.